# Exchange Server 2010,invalid attribute Max.MovesPerSourceMDB, MRS configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

I have a problem with exchange server 2010 on windows 2008 R2 Standard Server, Every 5-6 seconds exchange server is posting the following error in event log:

```
EventID: 1004, Name: MSExchange Mailbox Replication
>The Mailbox Replication service configuration is damaged.
>Error: Unrecognized attribute 'Max.MovesPerSourceMDB'. Note that attribute names are case->sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange >Server\V14\Bin\MSExchangeMailboxReplication.exe.config line 99).
```

The configuration file contains:

```
MRSConfiguration  MaxRetries = "60"
MaxCleanupRetries = "5"
MaxStallRetryPeriod = "00:15:00"
RetryDelay = "00:00:30"
MaxMoveHistoryLength = "2" 
Max.MovesPerSourceMDB = "5"
 MaxActiveMovesPerTargetMDB = "2"
 MaxActiveMovesPerSourceServer = "50"
 MaxActiveMovesPerTargetServer = "5"
 MaxTotalMovesPerMRS = "100"
 FullScanMoveJobsPollingPeriod = "00:10:00"
 MinimumTimeBeforePickingJobsFromSameDatabase = "00:00:04"
 ServerCountsNotOlderThan = "00:10:00"
 MRSAbandonedMoveJobDetectionTime = "01:00:00"
 BackoffIntervalForProxyConnectionLimitReached = "00:30:00"
 DataGuaranteeCheckPeriod = "00:00:10"
 DataGuaranteeTimeout = "00:30:00"
 DataGuaranteeLogRollDelay = "00:01:00"
 EnableDataGuaranteeCheck = "true"
 DisableMrsProxyCompression = "false"
 DisableMrsProxyBuffering = "false"
 MinBatchSize = "100"
 MinBatchSizeKB = "256"
```

Do you guys have a solution for fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive its because you have a full stop charachter after the word Max

It should be MaxActiveMovesPerSourceMDB

Comment: And even after removing the period there is this error: Unrecognized attribute 'MaxMovesPerSourceMDB'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\MSExchangeMailboxReplication.exe.config line 99)

Comment: Have you tried MaxActiveMovesPerSourceMDB?

Comment: It got fixed, when I replaced Max.MovesPerSourceMDB with MaxActiveMovesPerSourceMDB as you said, but couldn't understand, How the config file have an invalid entry by default, as we didn't modify the config file manually so far.